How to Refactor Laravel Livewire File Upload Functionality to Use Events and Listeners?
I am working on a Laravel Livewire application and need to refactor the file upload functionality to use an event and listener approach for better scalability and separation of concerns. I'm encountering issues where the processed_participants array is empty after implementing the new structure. Below are the details of my implementation and the issues I'm facing.
Current Implementation
Here's the original file_uploaded function in the CreateNewBatchForm Livewire component:
CreateNewBatchForm Livewire Component
public function file_uploaded(FileUpload $file_upload, $file_upload_type) {
    $this->file_uploaded_successfully = true;
    $this->file_upload = $file_upload;
    $this->file_upload_type = $file_upload_type;
    
    // Reset our array of processed participants
    $this->processed_participants = ['accepted' => [], 'rejected' => []];

    if ($file_upload_type == "xlsx" || $file_upload_type == "xls") {
        $import = new \App\Imports\ParticipantsImport();
        Excel::import($import, $file_upload->file_location);
        $participants = $import->get_participants();
    } else {
        $csv_data = Storage::get($file_upload->file_location);
        $lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $csv_data);
        $participants = [];
        foreach ($lines as $line) {
            $participants[] = str_getcsv($line);
        }
    }

    // Process participants here...
}

Refactoring Steps

Created an Event: FileUploaded with parameters FileUpload model instance and file type.

Implemented a Listener: ProcessUploadedFile to process the file.

Dispatched the Event: From the Livewire component replacing direct processing logic.


Issues Encountered
After refactoring, the processed_participants array remains empty despite files being uploaded successfully. There are no error messages logged, making it difficult to diagnose the issue.
Specific Questions

How can I ensure the event-driven architecture processes the file uploads correctly?

What could be causing the processed_participants array to return empty and how can I debug this issue effectively?


Environment

Laravel Version: 8.x

Livewire Version: 2.x

PHP Version: 7.4


What are the best practices for refactoring the file_uploaded method to use events and listeners in Laravel?

When you trigger an event listener, there is no response after, or can you expound further?

Please share your new event & listener code that you say is not working, as well as the code that displays the processed_participants within your Livewire component's view.
